# GRATIS MISRA checker for C

Tags: gratis, c, static-analysis, misra

Is there any gratis tool which checks C code for [MISRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_Industry_Software_Reliability_Association) compliance?

Standalone static code analysis if acceptable, any platform.

A bonus would be an IDE, plugin (preferably Eclipse, but any gratis IDE will do), or even a compiler, so that I can see MISRA non-compliance as I develop, not just when I remember to run the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing Open Source projects then [Coverity Scan](https://scan.coverity.com/) is available free but if you are developing closed source code then you will have to pay for a licence.

Coverity performs a wide variety of static analysis including MISRA and there are plugins for a number of IDEs.

Comment: Ppvoted for a good suggestion, even thought it doesn't match my request for gratis. I tried my best, but can't find hio much it costs. Do you know?

Comment: If you are programming an Open Source project then Coverty Scan is gratis. If not then you have to contact synopsys for a quote.

Comment: It is also worth noting that you can run Coverity Scan 8.5.0.1 from within appvayor (https://www.appveyor.com) which is free for open source, $29/month basic or $59/mo pro.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have passed it on & will no doubt hear nothing further from management.  Is there any reason why I should switch from Jenkins to AppVeyor?  On the one hand, I am always on the lookout for better tools, but otoh I have time invested in Jenkins (which is also gratis for non-FOSS). Just curious.